# I have a error in Display Member value,How to fix it?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am retrieving whole data from database in list?Now i have four class like:

Student class:

```
public class StudentTable
{
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public StudentTable()
    {
    }

    public StudentTable(string aStudentID, string aStudentName)
    {
        StudentID = aStudentID;
        StudentName = aStudentName;
    }
}
```

Course class

```
public class CourseTable
{
    public string CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }

    public CourseTable()
    {
    }

    public CourseTable(string aCourseID, string aCourseName, int aCredits)
    {
        CourseID = aCourseID;
        CourseName = aCourseName;
        Credits = aCredits;
    }
}
```

Enrollment class

```
public class Enrollment
{
    public StudentTable StudentData { get; set; }
    public CourseTable CourseData { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOE { get; set; }

    public Enrollment()
    {
    }

    public Enrollment(StudentTable aStudentData, CourseTable aCourseData, DateTime aDOE)
    {
        StudentData = aStudentData;
        CourseData = aCourseData;
        DOE = aDOE;
    }
}
```

StudentScore class:

```
public class StudentScore
{

    public Enrollment EnrollmentData { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public StudentScore()
    {
    }

    public StudentScore(Enrollment aEnrollmentData, int aScore)
    {
        EnrollmentData = aEnrollmentData;
        Score = aScore;
    }
}
```

and i retrieve the data from database through query now i want to display the StudentID from list but in the StudentScore Class i have EnorllmentData not StudentID.

```
try
{
    var aStudentScore = EnrollmentDB.GetAllScore();
    comboBox3.DataSource = aStudentScore;

    comboBox3.DisplayMember = "StudentID";
    comboBox3.ValueMember = "CourseID";
    //comboBox3.ValueMember = "Score";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
}
```

It show me a DisplayMember error can you please help me to fix it, becaouse in StudentScore class have no StudentID variable so How can i display the StudentID from StudentScore Class?

Comment: "It show me a DisplayMember error" - can you be more precise? *Always* give the error message in the question.

Comment: Do you rewrite from C# to VB.NET? Do you have error in C#, VB.NET or both? What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first you had the **Cannot bind to new display member** error which Jon solved by showing you how to use dot-notation.

After that you are now getting the **Unable to cast** error.  Without seeing that GetAllScore method I can't say exactly why.  However, you can do the heavy lifting yourself in code, and make the binding simple, by adding read-only properties to StudentScore to return what you want to use as the Display and Value Members.  (I have to say that using StudentID as a DisplayMember and CourseID as a ValueMember doesn't make any sense to me.)

Add something like this to your StudentScore:

```
public String UseAsDisplayMember
{
    get 
    {
        return EnrollmentData.StudentData.StudentID; 
    }
}
public string UseAsValueMember
{
    get 
    {
        return EnrollmentData.CourseData.CourseID; 
    }
}
```

Then set the data binding as:

```
comboBox3.DisplayMember = "UseAsDisplayMember";
comboBox3.ValueMember = "UseAsValueMember";
```

This should get you working, but it feels more like a band-aid than a real fix.

Answer (score 1):

Your `StudentScore` type doesn't expose `StudentID` or `CourseID`, but that's what you're trying to bind. How would you expect that to work?

You *may* be able to use:

```
comboBox3.DisplayMember = "EnrollmentData.StudentData.StudentID";
comboBox3.ValueMember = "EnrollmentData.CourseData.CourseID";
```

... it depends on whether whatever binding you're using is able to navigate properties that way.

As an aside, your naming of the `StudentTable` and `CourseTable` types is inappropriate - an instance of that doesn't represent a `StudentTable` - it represents *one row* in a table. Just calling those types `Student` and `Course` would make more sense.

Comment: now it shows this error: **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.RelatedPropertyManager' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager'.**

Comment: @user1059932: I'm afraid I don't know anything about that. It would help if you'd post the full stack trace though.

Comment: Firstly it shows: **Cannot bind to new display member. Parameter name: newDisplayMember**

Comment: @user1059932: Where? When? Sorry, but you've got to give better diagnostic information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit all the relevant information into your question.

Comment: @user1059932: Well you can start by changing your catch block so you don't just show the message and the type. Just print out `ex` itself... that will include the stack trace.